# Android Multiple RecyclerView (horizontal & Vertical) on 1 Fragment Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-recyclerview

I want use several **RecyclerView** on one page layout.

I need this list:

Method 1:

```
<ScrollView>
    <ViewPager></ViewPager> <!-- horizontal image slider 10 item -->
    <RecyclerView></RecyclerView> <!-- horizontal -->
    <RecyclerView></RecyclerView> <!-- gridview -->
    <RecyclerView></RecyclerView> <!-- horizontal -->
    <RecyclerView></RecyclerView> <!-- horizontal -->
    <RecyclerView></RecyclerView> <!-- gridview -->
    <RecyclerView></RecyclerView> <!-- horizontal -->
</ScrollView>
```

Method 2:

```
<Relativelayout>
    <RecyclerView>
        <!-- viewtype for ViewPager horizontal image slider 10 item -->
        <!-- viewtype for horizontal  -->
        <!-- viewtype for gridview -->
        <!-- viewtype for horizontal  -->
        <!-- viewtype for horizontal  -->
        <!-- viewtype for gridview -->
        <!-- viewtype for horizontal  -->
    </RecyclerView>
</Relativelayout>
```

To do this, I found two ways:

- one RecyclerView --> use `ItemViewType`
- Add All recycleview into one `ScrollView`

**Which method is correct?**

Each of these methods has problems, And I could not find way.

Issues:

- using by `<ScrollView>` method: laod all images out of screen before scroll to down. (but scroll is fast and smooth)
- using by **one recycleview (multiple item view type)** is very nested and scroll is not smooth and fast and is lagy.

How is the design of the list in GooglePlay Apps? (nested and smoothly)

thank you for help

Comment: You probably should use one RecyclerView and make the Adapter load the horizontal ones

Comment: One more thing, have you use `vertical Linearlayout` in `Scrollview` ?

Comment: @MayurRaval yes

Comment: @cricket_007 you mean: one RecyclerView and and **7** itemViiewType and Each viewType include one recyclerview ?

Comment: I only count 3 viewtypes. The normal vertical stuff, the ViewPager, and the horizontal lists.

Comment: @cricket_007 I've tested this method, but is laggy for millisecond on scroll down :(

Comment: @frzdno If you want to do a design like google play you can use this http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html .I have already tried it and it's smooth and fast.

Comment: If you want to use ScrollView and RecyclerView,then use NestedScrollView for multiple recycler Views inside it.

Comment: @AndroidGeek in `nestedScrollView` i shoud add `setNestedScrollingEnabled(true)`? and, Which method is correct?

Comment: @frzdno Actually,I had same problem using multiple Recycler views inside the ScrollView.It was not working properly for me.So,I searched and found that one must use Nested scrollview for such cases.I am posting example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution found:

Method 2 is better. using one `recycleView` with `ItemViewType`.
do not set setAdapter() in `onBindViewHolder` Which leads to lag. put steAdapter() in your ViewHolder and smooth scroll.

Comment: How to add infinite scroll in this?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this code:

```
      <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
          <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="vertical">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
             android:id="@+id/recylerView1"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recylerView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">            

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recylerView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

       <!--You can add as many recycler views you want here--> </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: I've used the `scrolView` method, but my issue is : load all image in scrollview before scroll down. `nestedScrollView` Resolve the issue?

Comment: Please try it once.My problem was that It was not loading all the recycler views for my case.It was missing few Views.

Comment: From where You are loading the images?

Comment: from network. i use fresco library to load recyclerView imageView items. all images load out side display. i want only load image on scroll :|

Comment: No need to add it.
I think that images must be loaded only on scrolling.

Comment: Exception raised during rendering: NestedScrollView can host only one direct child

Comment: Sorry.You must add linear layout as child of NestedScrollView and then put your view pager and other recycler views inside it

Comment: nestScrollView no differerent with scrollView. all images load before scroll down. :(